# Maven tag without release:prepare making branch changes

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When running `mvn release:prepare` it's doing these:

- Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sourcesPOMs
- Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
- Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you will be prompted for the versions to use)
- Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
- Run the project tests (preparation goals) against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order
- **Commit the modified POMs**
- Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)
- Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)
- Eventually run completion goal(s) against the project (since 2.2)
- **Commit the modified POMs**

Ref - https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Is it possible to get `mvn release:prepare` running without the **"Commit the modified POMs"** part? I don't want `mvn` to modify and push the `POM.xml` of the `branch` that I'm creating the tag from, but only push the tag to Git.

Also adding optional parameters like `suppressCommitBeforeTag=false` doesn't really help.

Comment: [`mvn -DdryRun=true release:prepare`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#dryRun)!?;)

Comment: If you don't like to having committing the modified pom files which means your tag does not represent the released state, but if you like you can change the https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-with-pom-mojo.html#releaseStrategyId (implement your own one of it)...